# Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)) for AxAcroPDF1 control

Tags: vb.net

I want to use AxAcroPDF1 control to view PDF files in my VB.net application. I added the libraries AcroPDFLib and AxAcroPDFLib to my project and dragged the control on to the form.

```
 AxAcroPDF1.src="Myfile.pdf".
```

Project is set to build on X86 environment and the option to Register for COM interop is checked. I have a 64 bit machine. I have googled this issue but did not find any solution that worked for me. Thanks, any pointers on this are appreciated.

```
Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CoCreateInstance(Guid& clsid, Object punkOuter, Int32 context, Guid& iid)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateWithoutLicense(Guid clsid)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateWithLicense(String license, Guid clsid)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstanceCore(Guid clsid)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstance()
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.GetOcxCreate()
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.TransitionUpTo(Int32 state)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateHandle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.EndInit()
   at Panel.InitializeComponent() in Panel.Designer.vb:line 115
   at Panel...............................
```

Comment: Have you set any other AxAcroPDF1 properties. More code can be helpful.

Comment: No, simply the src property.